# Sockets - how to deal with?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am getting an error in creating socket in **Android**

```
try {
        socket = new Socket(address, port);

        din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        pout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        }
```

So after running this piece of code, I'm getting my app crashed and i am not getting it, where i have made the mistake.

Comment: see the `logcat` output then: it will show the java stacktrace

Comment: internet permissions in manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, you cannot access the network without first declaring that your app wants to do that.
You need to add a permission line to the Android manifest file declaring that your app will use some network services.
Try adding this line to the AndroidManifest.xml file just before the `<application>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application....
```

Also please read [this for more info](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting).